# Cell required if another cell has value validation

Tags: excel, vba

There are two columns in my excel file

Column D and Column E

I have created a dropdown list so the user can chose an option from them

For Column D you can chose the following options:

- Boy
- Girl
- Woman
- Man

For Column E you can chose the following options:

- Study
- Works
- Both
- N/A

I have been trying to implement this with VBA in order to make a required validation for Column E rows.

So for example if I chose "Boy" or any option from the dropdown for Column D, then the Column E row should be required (cannot be empty).

Can this be achieved?  Thanks.

Comment: How do they "chose"? Is it a drop down, radio button or something else? Should there be different requirements? What do you even mean by required in a practical sense?

Comment: I suppose that if you choose "Girl", the code should return the same, respectively, the row of the changed cell. Is this supposition correct? If yes, how do you need to be returned?

Comment: It's a dropdown

Comment: @FaneDuru it's a dropdown where can they chose from

Comment: This is irrelevant... If the cell value is changed in this way or directly, the code I posted should work. Did you test it. Should the  code work differently if "girl" is selected? Did you  understand the code I provided?

Answer (score 0):

If my supposition in the above comment is correct, please, try the next way:

Copy the next cell in the sheet code module where the validated cells exist:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.cells.count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column = 4 Then                 'if a cell has been changed in column D:D
        UseCellEAddress Target.Offset(0, 1)  'call a Sub and pass the cell to the target right side, as parameter
    End If
End Sub
```

The event calls the next `Sub` which can deal with the received `Range` parameter:

```
Sub UseCellEAddress(rngE As Range)
    Debug.Print "Cell address: " & rngE.Address, "Row: " & rngE.row
    'do whatever you need with the cell in E:E
End Sub
```

The above `Sub` can be in the same sheet code module, or in a standard module...